# Multiple executions of one loop after key detected

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, macos-monterey

I have the code:

```
while True:
     if keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
          print(usr)
```

So when I run the rest of the program and get to the code, the code works! It detects me pressing 'i' on my keyboard. However, it prints the dictionary `usr` multiple times. Anyway I can fix this? I tried the `break` keyword but then it stops the whole program. Please help me! I'm sorry if this isn't the best question? I'm not too sure I care about the whole reputation thing, however, I want to make sure I'm making the right posts.

The whole code:

```
# My very own first game
# Completely made by Cyb3rst0rm

import keyboard

print('Hello, welcome to Terminal Adventure!')
q0 = input("What is your name? ") # q0, name
print('Nice to meet you ' + q0 + '!')

questions = ["Do you like fruit? Yes or No ", 
"Do you like vegetables? Yes or No ", 
"Do you play any sports? Yes or No ",
"Do you like chocolate? Yes or No ",
"What is your age? ", # index 4, question 5, q5, age
"What is your race? ", # index 5, question 6, q6, race
"What is your gender? ", # index 6, question 7, q7, gender
]

user = {}

def infoCall(usr):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
            print(usr)

def mainLoop():
    q1 = input(questions[0])
    if q1 == 'Yes':
        q1 = input("What fruit do you like? ")
        print("Cool! I can't eat " + q1 + " because I'm not a human.")
    elif q1 == 'No':
        print("Haha, you're not alone in that! ")
    q2 = input(questions[1])
    if q2 == 'No':
        print("Me neither! They're disgusting!")
    elif q2 == 'Yes':
        print("Weirdo, haha")
        q2 = input("What vegetable do you like? ")
        print("I'm not so sure about that one.")
    q3 = input(questions[2])
    if q3 == 'Yes':
        q3 = input("What sport? ")
        print(q3 + " sounds fun!")
    if q3 == 'No':
        print("Hey we're both couch-potatoes!")
    q4 = input(questions[3])
    if q4 == "No":
        q4 = input("Chocolate's amazing! Why don't you like it? ")
        print("I don't agree with that, I'm sorry, chocolate is amazing.")
    elif q4 == "Yes":
        q4 = input("Hey me too! What type of chocolate do you like? ")
        print("Cool! I like dark chocolate.")
    q5 = input(questions[4])
    q6 = input(questions[5])
    q7 = input(questions[6])
    user = {"name": q0, "age": q5, "race": q6, "gender": q7}
    print("Here is the information you entered!")
    print(user)
    infoCall(user)

def askBegin():
    begin = input("Shall we begin the game? Yes or No ")
    if begin == 'Yes':
        mainLoop()
    elif begin == 'No':
        quit
    else:
        print('Not an accepted answer! Please try again.')
        askBegin()

askBegin()
```

Comment: Do you mean when you press an "i" it should print the user and exit loop? and when you press other characters it should continue waiting for the "i"?

Comment: What I'm trying to go for is that when I press "i" it should print the dictionary "usr" ONCE.  If I press "i" again any point during the program, it should still print the dictionary "usr" once. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you should add `break` at the same level as `print()`. The cause of this behavior might be that `print` is much faster than `is_pressed`.

```
def infoCall(usr):
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed("i"):
            print(usr)
            break
```

If you want it continue forever, only print user if "i" is pressed, try this:

```
def infoCall(usr):
    while True:
        keyboard.wait("i"):
        print(usr)
```

Comment: It works thank you so much! (the second one, the first one stopped the whole program)

Comment: For the second one, with the `keyboard.wait` method, it's stopping and waiting the whole program. Like no other code after when I call the function `infoCall()` runs. I was hoping to get the "i" key detection simeltaneously as the other code runs. Is this possible?